# Login-Validation If Else Statement Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why when I have else statement added like this, the if statement is ignored. I put values that are true and the if statement is ignored the output always is my else code...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let userData = [
    {
      email: 'knorr@live.com',
      password: 'ksGuQbzYPpW'
    },
    {
      email: 'rddesign@msn.com',
      password: '9Q6urHqy'
    },
    {
      email: 'chaffar@yahoo.ca',
      password: '4xaz2pyk'
    },
    {
      email: 'fatelk@mac.com',
      password: 'TAePJSb2ACX'
    },
    {
      email: 'luebke@me.com',
      password: 'EyFY8uhX'
    },
    {
      email: 'amichalo@mac.com',
      password: 'c7muQ6bxcA9QJKS'
    },
    {
      email: 'mallanmba@yahoo.ca',
      password: 'NqCGLmGtcFU'
    },
    {
      email: 'isaacson@att.net',
      password: 'PMjRGUug7Ff73Kt'
    },
    {
      email: 'aracne@aol.com',
      password: 'sBJU7JJR7Qx6f55'
    },
    {
      email: 'boser@comcast.net',
      password: 'DMXQRNj7BHZ'
    },
    {
      email: 'gtaylor@verizon.net',
      password: 'AbefrKfkbxHbP3u'
    },
    {
      email: 'firstpr@comcast.net',
      password: 'PGWPUtcwP'
    },
    {
      email: 'sumdumass@sbcglobal.net',
      password: '2DrCpjkk9mm8bjW'
    },
    {
      email: 'campbell@yahoo.com',
      password: 'ZmYZgaDq6'
    },
    {
      email: 'wetter@me.com',
      password: 'ppTG3pGAe'
    },
    {
      email: 'british@verizon.net',
      password: '67SbpGYvPJ2'
    }
  ];

  $("#loginBtn").on("click", function() {
    let email = $("#email").val();
    let password = $("#pass").val();

    for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
      if (email === userData[i].email) {
        if (password === userData[i].password) {
          alert("Match");
        } else if (password !== userData[i].password) {
          alert("Incorrect Password");
        }

        break;
      } else {
        alert("Invalid Login");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have an off topic question. Is this a school assignment? Because this is a very insecure thing to do and SHOULD NOT be done in production.

Comment: The `else if` is completely unnecessary anyway; if the password equality test fails, then the password is definitely not equal. You just need an `else`.

Comment: Yes is school assignment, we haven't started back-end part yet

Comment: You should ALWAYS be checking for matching usernames and passwords on the server, with passwords stored encrypted. This code is easily hackable and easily exposes the usernames and passwords of all accounts. But if it’s just a learning exercise for school, then that’s okay.

Comment: `else` is unnecessary when using `break` at the end of an `if` block - just write your “else” code (`alert("Invalid Login");`) after the `if` statement

Comment: My question was how to fix the problem that everytime my if statement is ignored, on every input, the else statement is the output.. ....

Comment: Ignoring security issues, your data structure should be an object, not an array. This will let you avoid the loops and lookup up matches directly.

Comment: } else if ((i+1) === userData.length) {
        alert("Invalid Login");
      } ## reached the array limit without matching email

Answer (score 0):

I think it works, except it doesn't appear that it does. Because the if statement is in the loop, for every element in userData that is incorrect, "Invalid Login" will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't ignore your `if` statement. It works. 
 You may try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  let userData = [{ email: 'admin', 
                    password: '1234'
                 }, {
                    email: 'admin2',
                    password: '12345'
                 }];
                 
  $("#loginBtn").on("click", () => {
  
    let email = $("#email").val();
    let password = $("#pass").val();
    
    let pos = userData.map((user) => user.email).indexOf(email);
    if (pos !== -1) {
      alert((userData[pos].password === password) ? "match" 
            : "password invalid");
    } else { alert("user not found"); }

  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email" type="text"/>
<input id="pass" type="password"/>
<button id="loginBtn">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is okay and it works even if it has a lot of security matters. I tested myself and at a certain using a pair email and pass from the array there is a **MATCH**:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        
            <input id="email">
            <input id="password">
            <button id="sub" type="button">Sbmit</button>
        
        <script>
          
  let userData = [
    {
      email: 'knorr@live.com',
      password: 'ksGuQbzYPpW'
    },
    {
      email: 'rddesign@msn.com',
      password: '9Q6urHqy'
    },
    {
      email: 'chaffar@yahoo.ca',
      password: '4xaz2pyk'
    },
    {
      email: 'fatelk@mac.com',
      password: 'TAePJSb2ACX'
    },
    {
      email: 'luebke@me.com',
      password: 'EyFY8uhX'
    },
    {
      email: 'amichalo@mac.com',
      password: 'c7muQ6bxcA9QJKS'
    },
    {
      email: 'mallanmba@yahoo.ca',
      password: 'NqCGLmGtcFU'
    },
    {
      email: 'isaacson@att.net',
      password: 'PMjRGUug7Ff73Kt'
    },
    {
      email: 'aracne@aol.com',
      password: 'sBJU7JJR7Qx6f55'
    },
    {
      email: 'boser@comcast.net',
      password: 'DMXQRNj7BHZ'
    },
    {
      email: 'gtaylor@verizon.net',
      password: 'AbefrKfkbxHbP3u'
    },
    {
      email: 'firstpr@comcast.net',
      password: 'PGWPUtcwP'
    },
    {
      email: 'sumdumass@sbcglobal.net',
      password: '2DrCpjkk9mm8bjW'
    },
    {
      email: 'campbell@yahoo.com',
      password: 'ZmYZgaDq6'
    },
    {
      email: 'wetter@me.com',
      password: 'ppTG3pGAe'
    },
    {
      email: 'british@verizon.net',
      password: '67SbpGYvPJ2'
    }
  ];

  document.getElementById("sub").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    console.log(typeof email);
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
        console.log(typeof userData[i].email);
      if (email === userData[i].email) {
          
        if (password === userData[i].password) {
          alert("Match");
        } else if (password !== userData[i].password) {
          alert("Incorrect Password");
        }

        break;
      } else {
        alert("Invalid Login");
      }
    }
  });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```